# jqGridImport request not found

Tags: jqgrid

jqGridImport is not a function

On version 5.3.2, when I try to call the jqGridImport function, it cannot be found. But jqGridExport works just fine.

$('#myGrid').jqGrid('jqGridImport', options)
or
$('#myGrid').jqGridImport(options)

According to the Import/Export documentation it should work just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you use the Guriddo jqGrid, but read the old docs for jqGrid <=4.7 
The correct linkt is  [Guriddo documentation](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/persiststate/#other-methods)

With simple word you will need not to apply the method to the grid, but pass the id as parameter to it. Try:

```
$.jgrid.jqGridImport( "#myGrid", options );
```

Comment: Hi Tony, I just figured it out by myself and wanted to update when I saw your answer. Thank you so much. I do have one comment though: If you pass the '#' sign as part of the name, your JqID function will try to escape it ('#test' will be converted to '\#test') and then the jquery element won't match the table ID. Better not to include the '#' sign in the name.

Comment: Thanks. Will test your recommendation and if possible will fix the problem.